# Safari not showing elements with event listeners

Tags: html, safari

I'm not exactly sure what's going on, but I have some troubles with Safari.

I have some divs with data attributes like this:

```
<div data-vimeo="12345"></div>
```

Upon `window.onload` the content of these get's replaced with something like this:

```
 <div class="vimeo-placeholder">
   <div class="placeholder-headline">Vimeo-Video ausgeblendet</div>
   <div>Dieses Video kann erst geladen werden, nachdem Sie Ihre Zustimmung erteilen.</div>
   <div class="cookie-consent">Klicken Sie hier, um Ihre Zustimmung zu erteilen.</div>
</div>
```

Here's the thing: Safari doesn't show the last "cookie-consent" div and when I try to debug it in the console, upon clicking on the element, the console freezes.

Here's the CSS:

```
  .vimeo-placeholder {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
    height: 6rem;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    padding: 5rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    margin: 1rem;
  }

  .vimeo-placeholder .placeholder-headline {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  }

  .vimeo-placeholder .cookie-consent {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Anything else is shown. The only thing making the last div different from the other ones is that it has an event listener (click) attached.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? No idea what's going on. It works flawlessly in any other browser.

Thank you.

Comment: doubt anyone will be able to give you an answer with the information provided.

Comment: what'd you need @espascarello?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, stupid me.

This behavior was caused by the 'Hush' safari add-on which disables cookie notices which - obviously - worked.

So if you ever experience the console freezing when working with cookie consent solutions, make sure 'Hush' is turned off.